Не записываются данные из Firebase Realtime Database в TextView
private fun getNameDataFromDb() {

        val currentUser = Firebase.auth.currentUser
        val ref = databaseReference?.child(currentUser?.uid.toString())?.child("name")
        val listener = object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                val changedDatas = snapshot.getValue(Name::class.java)
                nameTextView.text = changedDatas?.name

            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                Log.w("MyApp", "Failed to read value.")
            }
        }
        ref?.addValueEventListener(listener)
    }

Класс Name:
package com.example.heartbeatapp

class Name(val name: String = "") {
    constructor() : this("")
}


А проблема-то в чем? databaseReference == null или ref == null или changedDatas == null? Это вы нам должны сказать, никто ваш код запускать не будет, да и не сможет.
